# How do I know when yellow split peas are cooked?

Tags: pulses

After having boiled for initially 10 minutes and then simmered for an hour my yellow split peas are still firm and a little gritty.

If cooked long enough do they ever get soft like a red kidney bean?

They are the [cheapest pulse on the shelf](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/food-cupboard/cooking-ingredients/pulses-lentils-and-beans/other-dried-pulses) and I'm beginning to think the least responsive to cooking.

I soak these overnight so they are fully re-hydrated by the time of cooking.

I cook in enough water to cover them.

Comment: How much water have you added for what quantity of split peas?

Comment: Soaking doesn't fully rehydrate, it just gets you a head start.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't added enough water. Split peas are dried, cooking re-hydrates them, but only if there's enough to for them to absorb.  You need to add at least double the water as peas, a bit like rice in that respect. It's also possible you have old peas, or they are a variety that simply needs a longer cooking time. Hard water can also slow down cooking.

Try using softened water if you can, and more of it. An overnight soak can also work wonders.

Answer (score 1):

I had that happen one time with my yellow split peas.  No matter cooking time they stayed 'gritty' like you said. I came to the conclusion (after reading up) that the batch had been stored far too long and/ or heat damaged during storage.